# Protractor timed out because $timeout and $interval

Tags: angularjs, timeout, intervals

I have a simple login test in protractor, wich is running fine before adding a method with timeout and interval. So I guess protractor is waiting for those components to finish. How to make my test works? Maybe if I use `$timeout` and `$interval` in other way?.

I'm using timeout and interval like a service in my angular project. Say *hello* **after** some lets say 10 seconds (`$timeout`) and keep printing this message 5 times (`$interval`) and print *bye* when the interval is finished.

**This is my e2e test:**

```
var LoginPage = require('loginPage');

describe('Should login', function() {

    var page;
    beforeEach(function() {

        page = new LoginPage();
        page.visit();

        browser.getLocationAbsUrl().then(function (url) {
            expect(url).toEqual('/loginform');
        });

        page.setUser('username');
        page.setPassword('123456');

        page.submitLogin();

    });

    it('should redirect to welcome page', function () {
        expect(browser.getCurrentUrl()).toContain('/welcome');
    });
});
```

**This is my block of code for the timer:**

```
// Say hello after 10 seconds and keep printing the message five times.
doTimer(10, 5);

function doTimer(forTimeout, forInterval) {

    var countDown;

    myTimeout = $timeout(function () {

        countDown = forInterval;

        myInterval = $interval(function() {
            countDown--;
            console.log("hello");
            if (countDown == 0) {
                console.log("bye");
            }
        }, 1000);

    }, forTimeout*1000);
}
```

So, without calling my method `doTimer` my test runs perfect. How can I handle this in order to get my test works fine?

Answer (score 0):

You should call your doTimer(10,5) after declaring function as shown below -

```
function doTimer(forTimeout, forInterval) {

    var countDown;

    myTimeout = $timeout(function () {

        countDown = forInterval;

        myInterval = $interval(function() {
            countDown--;
            console.log("hello");
            if (countDown == 0) {
                console.log("bye");
            }
        }, 1000);

    }, forTimeout*1000);
}

doTimer(10, 5);
```

You are calling the function even before protractor knows where the function is, so, try to declare the function first and then call it. Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm trying to test the redirection to welcome page. The timeout method executes when you are on the welcome page. So when I run my protractor I can see my browser redirecting to welcome page and it is fine, but it is waiting for 'dotimer'. In this scenario I just want to test my redirect page.

Comment: @razorblade, is your `dotimer()` function causing issues while the page is redirecting? If yes, then the dotimer function isn't able to execute the code in the function. Where are you using the dotimer() function in your e2e test?